# mi menu hamburguesa no muestra el contenido "bootstrap"

Tags: html, bootstrap, responsive

tal cual no me muestra el contenido el menu hamburguesa en responsive...
incluso intente solo copiar el codigo directamente de la documentacion bootstrap y nada...
senecesita algun jquery o JS?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  bg-primary borde-3 border-bottom border-primary">
<div class="container-fluid">
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand" style="color: black;">nombre</a>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- 
target="#menu"  style="color: #000 !important;">
<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</button>

<div id="menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-3">
<li class= "nav item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> inicio</a> </li>
<li class= "nav item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Nosotros</a> </li>
<li class= "nav item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Nuestros servicios</a> </li>
<li class= "nav item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Galeria</a> </li>
<li class= "nav item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Cotizacionez</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: añadiste los archivos `js` como indica el doc de `bootstrap`?

Comment: Que versión de bootstrap estas usando en las referencias?

Answer (score 1):

El error se genera a partir de un espacio en la siguiente línea: "data-bs- target" , lo correcto es "data-bs-target"(sin espacios).

Resultado:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg   borde-3 border-bottom border-primary">
<div class="container-fluid">
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand" style="color: black;">nombre</a>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#menu"  style="color: #000 !important;">
<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</button>

<div id="menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-3">
<li class= "nav item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> inicio</a> </li>
<li class= "nav item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Nosotros</a> </li>
<li class= "nav item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Nuestros servicios</a> </li>
<li class= "nav item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Galeria</a> </li>
<li class= "nav item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"> Cotizacionez</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: El OP utiliza Bootstrap 5, no 4

Comment: amigo, he modificado la respuesta. se modificó el código a bootstrap 5